# Database query to handle when specific rows don't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Sorry for the bad title, it is hard to explain in one sentence what I am having problems with. So I have a stats database for basketball. What I am trying to do is group the stats for one team in one row then group all the stats this team played against in one other row. What I have now works if there are opponent stats in the database, but it is possible to not have opponent stats and just have the team stats. Hard to explain why, so please just go with that.

So lets say I have 3 rows like this:

```
COMP_ID | TEAM_ID | OFF_REB | DEF_REB
  1     |  100   |   5     |    4
  2     |  100   |   1     |    1
  3     |  100   |   3     |    7
```

Basically, there are 3 games, and I only have team 100's stats. I would like to get all of the OFF and DEF rebounds for team 100 in a row and then all of the opponent OFF and DEF rebounds in another row. If there are no opponent stats, just 0's will be fine.

FYI - What I do now is do a group by to package the team 100's stats together and also to package the opponent stats together. For the TEAM_ID of the opponent stats, I group them into -999 value so I know they are opponent values.

Here is the query I have now:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TEAM_ID <> 100 THEN -999 ELSE 100 END AS TEAM_ID, SUM(OFF_REB+DEF_REB) REBS
FROM V_STATS_COMP
WHERE COMP_ID IN (SELECT COMP_ID FROM COMPETITIONS WHERE HOME_ID = 100 OR VIS_ID = 100)
GROUP BY CASE WHEN TEAM_ID <> 100 THEN -999 ELSE 100 END
ORDER BY TEAM_ID
```

With this query, I get only 1 row back and thats for team 100. How do I adjust it to get the -999 row even if there are no stats available?

Edit to show desired results:

```
TEAM_ID | REBS
  100   |  21
 -999   |  0
```

Of course if there were opponent stats, id like to see their REBS value.

Comment: what is your subquery returning if you run it on its own?

Comment: In this example, it would return 1,2,3 (all 3 competitions). It could return more competitions if they are in the future (havent been played yet). so it could be 1,2,3,4,5,6....100.

Comment: can you please post an example of the results you'd like to see?

Comment: Sure, just edited the post. It is at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query below will ensure that you have -999, by adding union to you result set with 0, and it will not affect your resulting sum even if you already have -999:

```
    SELECT
         TEAM_ID
        ,SUM(REBS) REBS
    FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                  CASE WHEN TEAM_ID <> 100 THEN -999 ELSE 100 END AS TEAM_ID
                , ISNULL(OFF_REB,0)+ISNULL(DEF_REB,0) REBS
            FROM 
                V_STATS_COMP
            WHERE 
                COMP_ID IN (SELECT COMP_ID FROM COMPETITIONS WHERE HOME_ID = 100 OR VIS_ID = 100)
            UNION
            SELECT -999 TEAM_ID, 0 REBS
        ) as vwStats
    GROUP BY 
        vwStats.TEAM_ID
    ORDER BY 
        vwStats.TEAM_ID DESC
```

Comment: When I run this query, I am close but I get team 100's REBS value for the -999 row. Rather than 0 for it.

Comment: This is the link to the working code that returns result set as in your example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dae9d/2

Comment: You are right. I will look to see what I am doing wrong. Your example does seem to work in the link.

Comment: Ok I messsed up. I believe yours does work. I was testing against another team and they just so happened to have had the same as the real team. Two times in a row I tested against a team with all opponent totals equaling that teams value.  Thanks!